# Filter JSON data by multiple properties

Tags: javascript, json

I have JSON data that looks like in **data.json**. My goal is to let the user filter the data combined (like filter by category 1 and 3) by category 1-4. For that, I grab the option the user selected with *getSelectedFilterOption* from **api.js**. Then, I wrote a function with all 16 possibilites of filtering in *filterRowsByOption* from **api.js** That was my naive way of making it work (and it does), but I don't think that it is a practical way. Especially, it is not scalable like if I want to filter by 5 categories combined in the futher, I'd had to write all 32 possibilities out.

Is there a more convenient way to achieve what I want?

Thanks in advance.

*data.json*

```
{
    (...),
    "category1": "a",
    "category2": "b",
    "category3": "c",
    "category4": "d",
    (...)
}
```

*index.php*

```
<select id="filterCategory1" class="form-select">
   <option selected>All</option>
   <?php filter_cat1(); ?>
</select>
<select id="filterCategory2" class="form-select">
   <option selected>All</option>
   <?php filter_cat2(); ?>
</select>
<select id="filterCategory3" class="form-select">
   <option selected>All</option>
   <?php filter_cat3(); ?>
</select>
<select id="filterCategory1" class="form-select">
   <option selected>All</option>
   <?php filter_cat4(); ?>
</select>
```

*api.js*

```
function getSelectedFilterOption(data) {
    let selectedFilterOptions = ["All", "All", "All", "All"]; // initial state
    let selectedFilterOption = [];

    const selectFilter = document.querySelectorAll("#filterCategory1, #filterCategory2, #filterCategory3, #filterCategory4");

    for (let i = 0; i < selectFilter.length; i++) {
        selectFilter[i].addEventListener("change", function(e) {
            
            selectedFilterOption[i] = selectFilter[i].options[selectFilter[i].selectedIndex].text;
            
            selectedFilterOptions[i] = selectedFilterOption[i];
            console.log(selectedFilterOptions);
            filterRowsByOption(data, selectedFilterOptions);
        });
    }
}

function filterRowsByOption(data, selectedFilterOptions) {
    const container = document.querySelector(".container");

    container.innerHTML = "";

    let filteredData = data;

    // no filter
    if (selectedFilterOptions[0] === "All" && selectedFilterOptions[1] === "All" && selectedFilterOptions[2] === "All" && selectedFilterOptions[3] === "All") {
        displayAllRows(data);
    }

    // category1 chosen, category2 chosen, category3 chosen, category4 chosen
    else if (selectedFilterOptions[0] !== "All" && selectedFilterOptions[1] !== "All" && selectedFilterOptions[2] !== "All" && selectedFilterOptions[3] !== "All") {
        filteredData = data.filter(row => row.category1 === selectedFilterOptions[0] && row.category2 === selectedFilterOptions[1] && row.category3 === selectedFilterOptions[2] && row.category4 === selectedFilterOptions[3]);
    }

    // category1 chosen, category2 chosen, category3 chosen
    else if...
(...)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course you shouldn't repeat your self more than twice. I repeated the html though for demonstration purpose.

About this solution: `filter` the array by comparing the categories which are not empty.

```js
var data = [{
    "category1": "1",
    "category2": "2",
    "category3": "2",
    "category4": "1",
  },
  {
    "category1": "1",
    "category2": "2",
    "category3": "3",
    "category4": "4",
  }
];

var selects = document.querySelectorAll("[data-category]");
selects.forEach(function(select) {
  select.addEventListener("change", apply_filters);
})

function apply_filters() {
  var result = data.filter(function(obj) {
    var ok = true;
    selects.forEach(function(select) {
      var category = select.getAttribute("data-category");
      ok = ok && (select.value ? obj[category] == select.value : true)
    })
    return ok;
  })

  console.log(result);
}
```

```html
<select id="filterCategory1" data-category="category1" class="form-select">
  <option value="" selected>All Category1</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
<select id="filterCategory2" data-category="category2" class="form-select">
  <option value="" selected>All Category2</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
<select id="filterCategory3" data-category="category3" class="form-select">
  <option value="" selected>All Category3</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
<select id="filterCategory1" data-category="category4" class="form-select">
  <option value="" selected>All Category4</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: There is never any benefit in repeating an option's text as its `value` attribute.   When the attribute value is identical to the text, remove the attribute declaration to prevent bloating your HTML markup.

Comment: I just noticed that when I left out the `value=""` for the first option and was surprised to get value `"All Category1"` instead of `""`.  It's a matter of opinion whether to add verbosity or not.

Comment: Exactly.  In the case of `value=""` and `All Category1`, the text and `value` are not identical.  Verbosity is not beneficial when there is no increase to the comprehensibility of the code.  When you are re-stating the same value, you are not writing DRY code (which is what your answer recommends from the start).

Comment: @ITgoldman Thanks for your answer. If I adapt your solution to my project though, result is an empty array and the console says "data.filter is not a function". I'm not sure why this is happening - could you give me more insight on this?

Comment: `data` (as I understood it) should be an array of objects like in my example. What does the `console.log(data)` says?